# Modal Register Panel Button Save Click

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

Objective: I have a register panel to sign up.

Problem:  Signup button click doesnt work.

When I removed `id=register_panel` it perfectly works but modal popup doesnt work. 
I did not use ajax. 
How can I make the button click event work on this modal popup?

**Code :**

```
<div id="register_panel" class="mfp-hide loginbox-popup auth-popup" >
   <div class="inner-container register-panel auth-popup-panel">
      <h3 class="m_title m_title_ext text-custom auth-popup-title">YENİ HESAP</h3>
      <div class="register_panel" >
         <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form ">
            <asp:TextBox type="text" id="txtUsername" name="user_login" class="form-control inputbox kl-fancy-form-input kl-fw-input" placeholder="KULLANICI ADI" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Zorunlu Alan" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"
               runat="server" />
            <label class="kl-font-alt kl-fancy-form-label">AD SOYAD</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form ">
            <asp:TextBox type="text" id="txtTelefon" MaxLength="11"  name="user_login" class="form-control inputbox kl-fancy-form-input kl-fw-input" placeholder="532 532 32 32" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Zorunlu Alan" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtTelefon"
               runat="server" />
            <label class="kl-font-alt kl-fancy-form-label">TELEFON</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form">
            <asp:TextBox  type="text" id="txtEmail" name="user_email" class="form-control inputbox kl-fancy-form-input kl-fw-input" placeholder="your-email@website.com" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*Zorunlu Alan" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
               ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
               ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Geçersiz Mail Adresi." />
            <label class="kl-font-alt kl-fancy-form-label">EMAİL</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form">
            <asp:TextBox type="password" id="txtPassword" name="user_password" class="form-control inputbox kl-fancy-form-input kl-fw-input" placeholder="*****" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*Zorunlu Alan" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
               runat="server" />
            <label class="kl-font-alt kl-fancy-form-label">PAROLA</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group kl-fancy-form">
            <asp:TextBox type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" name="user_password2" class="form-control inputbox kl-fancy-form-input kl-fw-input" placeholder="*****" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="Parolalar eşleşmedi." ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"
               ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" />
            <label class="kl-font-alt kl-fancy-form-label">PAROLA(TEKRAR)</label>
         </div>
         <asp:Button  id="SignUp" OnClick="SignUp_Click1" class="btn-fullcolor"   runat="server" Text="KAYIT OL" />
         **here is button save click**
         <div class="links auth-popup-links">
            <a href="#login_panel" class="kl-login-box auth-popup-link">ZATEN BİR HESABINIZ MI VAR?</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Write the JavaScript code you use? Also explain the problem a bit more.

Comment: İ have not js code.  İ want to register panel on modal popup but signup button click doesnt work on modal popup. when i removed id=register_panel it works. how can i work button click event on modal popup? friends..

Comment: Without using JavaScript <form> tags should try.

Comment: Also there is an error in the console?

Comment: there is no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` property in your button:

```
<asp:Button id="SignUp" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
    OnClick="SignUp_Click1" runat="server" Text="KAYIT OL" />
```

Comment: thank you for answering asif ali but it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: I can not give an event to the asp button anywhere on the page, not just on the panel. this is due to the register_panel style file.